# Understanding simple sorting script , that compares values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was just searching for a simple jquery sorting script and found this online:

```
$(function() {
    $('ol').each(function() {
        var matches = $('li', this).filter(function() { // Each item
            var text = $(this).text();
            return $('ul.three li').filter(function() { // Are there matches in .three?
                return $(this).text() == text;
            }).length > 0;
        }).length;
        $('li:last', this).text((matches * 10) + ' Points');
    });
});
```

**[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/wemtzx76/5/)**

Notice how the values of the first 2 tables are compared with that of the values of the third table. now my question is about how `matches` is incremented, i went through the whole script, but don't quite understand how matches gets a value of 4 and 2 for the first and second table respectively(displayed in the respective table as 40 and 20). I understand the usage of the `filter` function, but don't quite understand how matches gets its value, I know the `length` property is involved, i see it at the end of the return statement, But still don't quite understand how is matches incremented ?

Comment: `filter` returns the elements that matched the filter, basically, and then `length` returns the size of the items array.. What is it exactly what you don't understand?

Comment: @PabloMatíasGomez , how does match get populated with 4 the first time ? , if you can answer this , you've answered my question .

Comment: Ii iterates every `li` in that `ol` and compares each of them to see if it's texts is in any of the `li`'s in `.three` .. And as you can see, there are four. So the filter returns that four `li` elements in an array (not reaaly an array, but a "jQuery array") and then, the `length` is 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('ol').each(function() {
        var matches = $('li', this).filter(function() { // Each item
```

Here it will iterate over every `li` item that ins contained inside the `ol` element that is currently being iterated

```
            var text = $(this).text();
            return $('ul.three li').filter(function() { // Are there matches in .three?
                return $(this).text() == text;
            }).length > 0;
```

Here it will search in the `ul` with the class `three` if there is any `li` that has the same text as the one `li` that is being iterated. The `filter` function will return every element that matches the search, of course if all texts are different, it will return one element or none. Therefore, when it checks for it `length > 0` what is doing is checking if there was at least one element that matched (aka: if this text was in  `.three`. So here if it returns true, it will we counter for the previous filter.

```
        }).length;
```

Here, the same as before, but with the outer filter, to check how many where found. Therefore, for the first one, the value is 4.

```
        $('li:last', this).text((matches * 10) + ' Points');
    });
});
```

Comment: @Pablo Thanks ! will go though ur answer !